# Stacked Area Chart Excel, 3 Series Negative Problems

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, formatting

I am trying to create a chart similar to this original chart. I'm having troubles with the negative values. The red area falls negative when I chart it as a stacked chart.

It seems like it should be stacked when positive but not when negative, but I'm not sure.

[XLS file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sjEtUjON1BDOoFpRUQnxrM0XHkiCl8Rw/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=112102274667866102474&rtpof=true&sd=true)

[image: original version]

[image: excel version]

Here's a subset of the dataset, including the period with the negative values.

| Date | Top8 | Rest | SPX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/1/2023 | 0.0282 | 0.0037 | 0.032 |
| 3/2/2023 | 0.0298 | 0.0101 | 0.0399 |
| 3/3/2023 | 0.0356 | 0.0212 | 0.0568 |
| 3/6/2023 | 0.0369 | 0.0207 | 0.0576 |
| 3/7/2023 | 0.0343 | 0.0071 | 0.0414 |
| 3/8/2023 | 0.0351 | 0.0079 | 0.043 |
| 3/9/2023 | 0.0315 | -0.0076 | 0.0239 |
| 3/10/2023 | 0.0284 | -0.0192 | 0.0091 |
| 3/13/2023 | 0.0312 | -0.0235 | 0.0076 |
| 3/14/2023 | 0.0371 | -0.0126 | 0.0245 |
| 3/15/2023 | 0.0396 | -0.0222 | 0.0174 |
| 3/16/2023 | 0.0468 | -0.0114 | 0.0354 |
| 3/17/2023 | 0.0465 | -0.0225 | 0.024 |
| 3/20/2023 | 0.046 | -0.0129 | 0.0331 |
| 3/21/2023 | 0.0504 | -0.0038 | 0.0466 |
| 3/22/2023 | 0.048 | -0.0185 | 0.0295 |
| 3/23/2023 | 0.0512 | -0.0186 | 0.0326 |
| 3/24/2023 | 0.052 | -0.0136 | 0.0385 |
| 3/27/2023 | 0.0492 | -0.0091 | 0.0402 |
| 3/28/2023 | 0.0477 | -0.0091 | 0.0386 |
| 3/29/2023 | 0.0518 | 0.0016 | 0.0533 |
| 3/30/2023 | 0.0538 | 0.0057 | 0.0595 |
| 3/31/2023 | 0.0581 | 0.0167 | 0.0748 |

Comment: Looks fine to me. Maybe show us an example with a minimal data set and show us what your expected result for that data set should be

Comment: Other than a different data set and color I see virtually no difference between those charts.

Comment: @Ramhound i want to separate the negative part essentially, basically want it to stack when positive and be separate when negative.
Green line should be the sum of red and blue, but the red data series does not go negative in the middle (march 2023)

Comment: @SilverSamwise Could you please share the data as well. Otherwise there is no way to reproduce it.

Comment: @karl added the link to the post.

Comment: Please don't link to an external file. Include sample data as a markdown table instead. Otherwise your question becomes useless in the future when the link goes dead. Also, some people will not download files from unknown sources

Comment: The chart from biancoresearch shows H1 returns of 13.71% but the data in column AA of your sheet show 16.9%. At least a few people agree the original chart is wrong: https://twitter.com/MNupdate/status/1678837802778214403?s=20

Comment: @FlexYourData yeah their data is wrong, I just like the format of the chart and am doing it correctly with the right numbers

Comment: When I opened the file, the SPX is all above zero, Top 8 is all above zero except for a few points at the beginning and "rest" has below zero values in March only and one or two in January. It doesn't look like the original chart or your second image in the post, so I'm confused.